# Is there a way to convert/standardize text into Integer in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-re

I have a dataframe with a column showing time(in minutes) spent for organizing each inventory item. The goal is to show minutes spent in either integer or float. However, the value in this column is not clean, see some example below. Is there a way to standardized and convert everything to an integer or float? (For example, 10 hours should be 600 minutes)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = { 'min':['420','450','480','512','560','10 hours', '10.5 hours',
'420 (all inventory)','3h ', '4.1 hours', '60**','6h', '7hours  ']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
```

The desired output is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `regex` for this kind of problem.

```
import regex as re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = { 'min':['420','450','480','512','560','10 hours', '10.5 hours',
'420 (all inventory)','3h ', '4.1 hours', '60**','6h', '7hours  ']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)

# Copy Dataframe for iteration
# Created a empty  numpy array for parsing by index
arr = np.zeros(df1.shape[0])
df1_copy = df1.copy()

for i,j in df1_copy.iterrows():
    if "h" in j["min"]:
        j["min"] = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z()\s]","",j["min"])
        j["min"] = float(j["min"])
        arr[i] = float(j["min"]*60)
    else:
        j["min"] = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z()**\s]","",j["min"])
        j["min"] = float(j["min"])
        arr[i] = float(j["min"])


df1["min_clean"] = arr
print(df1)
                    min  min_clean
0                   420      420.0
1                   450      450.0
2                   480      480.0
3                   512      512.0
4                   560      560.0
5              10 hours      600.0
6            10.5 hours      630.0
7   420 (all inventory)      420.0
8                   3h       180.0
9             4.1 hours      246.0
10                 60**       60.0
11                   6h      360.0
12             7hours        420.0
```

Comment: Thanks JAdel a lot for your helps. When I run this code against the real dataset , I am seeing error saying "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable". I am sure the entire column is string, not int. Would you mind to give me some advice on this? Thanks.

Comment: I replaced j["min"] with str(j["min"]) and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I currently don't know `pandas` but this solution (using regex) could help

```py
import re

df1 = { 'min':['420','450','480','512','560','10 hours', '10.5 hours',
'420 (all inventory)','3h ', '4.1 hours', '60**','6h', '7hours  ']}

def mins(s):
    if re.match(r"\d*\.?\d+ *(h|hour)", s):
        l = re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", s).split(".")
        m = int(l[0]) * 60
        if len(l) != 1:
            m += int(l[1]) * 6
        return m
    return int(re.sub(r"\D", "", s))

min_clear = map(mins, df1["min"])
print(list(min_clear))

# output: [420, 450, 480, 512, 560, 600, 630, 420, 180, 246, 60, 360, 420]
```

You could later add `min_clear` to the `DataFrame`

Btw, I am just a beginner; if any use case fails, tell me and I will try to improve this.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Rishi for your helps on this! I realized in my real dataset, I have much more messy data that does not follow a certain pattern, I will test around your approach and see how things go.

Comment: Sure. That's great! :D